# Build xpra on local directory without root privileges

Tags: compiling, python, non-root-user, xpra

I am trying to build xpra on local directory without root privileges. The `xpra` official site says: https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Building

> **Building with distutils**
>
> For installing into a local ./install directory as a normal user,
>   simply run:
>
> ```
> ./setup.py install --home=./install
> ```
>
> You then have to add the local installation directory to your
>   PYTHONPATH whenever you want to use xpra:
>
> ```
> PYTHONPATH=./install/lib*/python xpra ...
> ```

However it still tries to install python code in the global (write protected directories)

```
error: could not create '/usr/apps/python/etc': Read-only file system
```

after doing:

```
$ mkdir install
$ pwd
/home/user/soft/xpra/src
$ export PYTHONPATH=./install/lib/python/xpra #also tried without this.
$ ./setup.py install --home=./install
```

Do you know of any workaround to avoid writing to the global directory?

Comment: There were fixes in this area recently, try a newer version.

Comment: @totaam, Thanks, I am trying this on Fedora at the moment, I get this error `gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. This is from Xpra sources version 2.0.3.

Comment: You are missing the rpm build tools: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624428/